# Responsive flex layout with auto-filled vertical gap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, fluid-layout

Sorry I even don't know how describe my questions with proper terms for the title or don't know if this question is stupid. But here is my problem: I have some grids shape like 1x1, 2x1, 2x2 and 1x2 boxes, they may randomly appear with no specific order and I want these grids tiling on my page.
What I have:

```html
<html>
    <style>
        .container
        {
            display:flex;
            flex-direction:row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        .b11
        {
            background-color:#1b6d85;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
        }
        .b21
        {
            background-color:#8a6d3b;
            width:200px;
            height:100px;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
        }
        .b22
        {
            background-color:#2aabd2;
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="b11"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
            <div class="b11"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
            <div class="b22"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
            <div class="b11"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
            <div class="b11"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
            <div class="b11"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the result is (under arbitrary screen width, e.g. 760px):
[image]

Since there is a 2x2 box among the items, it leave a gap for the whole row. Is there any way these boxes can be placed as tight as possible (like stacking together from left to right, up to bottom) without any row gap?

[image]

Comment: I think you should use CSS Grid for this and not Flexbox. Flexbox is best for arranging elements in either a single row, or a single column. Grid is best for arranging elements in multiple rows and columns.

Comment: @AndreF thanks after some searchings i just realized that, i'm gonna look into a bit CSS grid layout see if I can make it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and i have solution. You need to use flex: 1; for your all item will be alignment. For Example:

```css
.container
        {
            display:flex;
            flex-direction:row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        .container > * {
            flex: 1;
        }
        .b11
        {
            background-color:#1b6d85;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
        }
        .container .b21 {
            flex: 2;
        }
        .b21
        {
            background-color:#8a6d3b;
            width:200px;
            height:100px;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
        }
        .b22
        {
            background-color:#2aabd2;
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="b11"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
            <div class="b11"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
            <div class="b22"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
            <div class="b11"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
            <div class="b11"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
            <div class="b11"></div>
            <div class="b21"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can tried this.

Comment: i tried unfortunately it's not right. I use Chrome 69. what is your browser?